# Иконка вместо скролла

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Как можно поставить свою иконку вместо стандартного скролла? куда копать?

Comment: Эм.. Ты б хоть картинку нарисовал, что хочешь получить. А вообще, уопать сюда: https://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/

Comment: Кастомизировать скролл можно только в хроме вроде (ну и других браузерах с webkit). Как вариант можешь рассмотреть эмуляцию скроллбара на JS. Вот например - https://grsmto.github.io/simplebar/

Comment: Кстати, при чем тут reactjs?

Comment: на react все реализую прост)

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите тут, такие вопросы уже  задавали
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12727422/it-is-possible-to-specify-the-scrollbar-image-with-html5
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_scrollbar.asp